# Muting shutter sound on video recording

Tags: android, video, camera, shutter

I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121660/how-to-record-video-from-background-of-application-android) code for my camera application. But I am getting shutter sound on start and end of the recording, which I want to disable. I did changes mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476791/android-mute-camera-shutter-sound), but its not working. Please help!!

Answer (score 4):

I was also facing the same problem but the following snippet worked for me,

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1){
              mCamera.enableShutterSound(false);

        }
        else{
                AudioManager audio= (AudioManager)this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, 0,   AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
             }
```

Hope it will help you too.

Answer (score 1):

On some devices(depends on market there it was sold) it is not possible at all. Nothing can help if it so.

Comment: So it depends on the device?...I tested it on Micromax A110 it did not work