# Mute capture sound on camera (using surfaceview)

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview

I want to mute the capture sound, when i take a picture using surfaceview, but it just won't mute.
I tried like they say in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14581477/2371477

I also tried it like this:https://stackoverflow.com/a/14141059/2371477
but that won't work either.

Why won't the shutter mute while using the surfaceview?

Comment: If you manually mute all sound on your phone, does the shutter sound still play? If it does, it might not be possible to mute the sutter sound on the phone you're using.

Comment: If I mute it on my phone, manually or programmaticaly, the shutter sound will always play. @Michael but when i use the normal camera app it does't make that sound