# How to Disable the sound in this app ( when i take a picture) ? i don't know where this sound come from?

Tags: android

I have a lot of sounds to play but not this default sound, I don't know where this sound come from ?

```
 private final ShutterCallback mShutterCallback = new ShutterCallback();    
//when i take it
        mCameraDevice.takePicture(mShutterCallback, mRawPictureCallback,
                    mPostViewPictureCallback, new JpegPictureCallback(loc));    

    private final class ShutterCallback implements
            android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback {
        public void onShutter() {
            mShutterCallbackTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            mShutterLag = mShutterCallbackTime - mCaptureStartTime;
            Log.v(TAG, "mShutterLag = " + mShutterLag + "ms");
            clearFocusState();
        }
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [android mute camera shutter sound?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476791/android-mute-camera-shutter-sound)

Comment: Bear in mind that this may be [illegal in some countries](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=japan+shutter+sound+law&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use Below code before getting the button clicked**

```
 AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    mgr.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, true);
```

**And these two lines just after the image get captured:**

```
AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
mgr.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, false);
```

Comment: Hey.. thnx.. plz accept my answer as it seems it worked